# How to configure jsonServer in gulp using typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, gulp

I had configured json server previously and was starting it using below code:
I am refering the below git repo for this.

[Starting angular2 project with gulp](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed)

**gulp-live-server.js**

```
var gulpCore = require('gulp');
var gulpParam = require('gulp-param');
var gulpExpressServer = require('gulp-express');
var gulp = gulpParam(gulpCore, process.argv);

//server will be running on port 3100 if not explicitly specified as below
gulp.task('server', function (port,env, package) {
console.log('IN LIVVEEEEEEEEE SERVERRRRR --->>'+' port passed:' + port+ ' command line args:' + process.argv+ ' package:' +package+' env:' +env );

var expressPort = isNaN(port + '') ? 3200 : port || 3200;
var jsonServerStarter = 'server/json-server-starter.js';

gulpExpressServer.run([jsonServerStarter], { env: { expressPort: expressPort } });

    gulp.watch(['db.json'], function (event) {
        console.log('abt to notify for db.json');
        //gulpExpressServer.notify(event);
    });

});
gulp.task('default', ['server']);
```

But now I am using an angular2 app, so in order to use the json-server I need to start it using `gulpfile.ts`,So far I have this:

```
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import * as runSequence from 'run-sequence';

import { PROJECT_TASKS_DIR, SEED_TASKS_DIR } from './tools/config';
import { loadTasks } from './tools/utils';


loadTasks(SEED_TASKS_DIR);
loadTasks(PROJECT_TASKS_DIR);


// --------------
// Build dev.
gulp.task('build.dev', (done: any) =>
   runSequence(//'clean.dev',
//              'tslint',
//              'css-lint',
          'build.assets.dev',
          'build.html_css',
          'build.js.dev',
          'build.index.dev',
          done));

// --------------
// Build dev watch.
gulp.task('build.dev.watch', (done: any) =>
  runSequence('build.dev',
          'watch.dev',
          done));

// --------------
// Build prod.
gulp.task('build.prod', (done: any) =>
  runSequence('clean.prod',
          'tslint',
          'css-lint',
          'build.assets.prod',
          'build.html_css',
          'copy.js.prod',
          'build.js.prod',
          'build.bundles',
          'build.bundles.app',
          'build.index.prod',
          done));   

// --------------
// Serve dev
gulp.task('serve.dev', (done: any) =>
  runSequence('build.dev',
          'server.start',
          'watch.dev',
          done)); 


// --------------
// Serve prod
gulp.task('serve.prod', (done: any) =>
  runSequence('build.prod',
          'server.prod',
          done));

//---------------
//json server
//not sure how to configure json-server here.
```

But I am not sure about how to configure the json-server in typescript.
any inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I searched , I finally found a approach to do this.
Configure your project with this [angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed).

Thus your live-server of anuglar2 picks up the gulp and then you can start your json-server by adding it to the `gulpfile.js`.
So live-server instantiates the gulp which further triggers json-server.

it finally worked for me.